# Showing compiled web application without VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

I have an already compiled web application on Visual Studio 2012.

I want to show it on my browser, using IIS, without open again VS. Is there this possibility?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy the appliction on your IIS. Also you have to activate IIS and ASP.NET features if they are not already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go back into VS and assuming this is a ASP.NET MVC or Web API application, then in IIS:

- Right click on Sites, and Add Web Site
- Set the site name, physical path (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/applicationName), and host name etc (be sure to add to the hosts file)
- Once you've created the site, go to your application pool and make sure you're on the right version of .NET (by going through advanced settings)

In the applicationName directory, put in your bin, app_start, app_data, fonts, scripts, views, etc folders. Also, you will need the Global.asax and obviously Web.config

Answer (score 0):

As you have a compiled Web Application in VS I assume you used IIS Express during development.

In case you want to run in on local IIS go to the project properties (right click the project node in the Solution Explorer), select the Web Tab, choose Local IIS and create a virtual directory (Button on the right side).

If you want to run the Web Application on another server, right click the project node and choose Publish... You can export via FTP or to a directory, from where you can copy/paste to your target server.